# How to remove the shadow effect on windows in CentOS, for Virtualbox seamless mode?

Tags: themes, virtualbox, centos7, gnome

Per the title, anyone know how to remove the window shadow effect in CentOS? I'm running CentOS as a VM in virtualbox and, in seamless mode, the shadow effect is leading to an annoying border around my windows.

Thanks!

Comment: I found this thread it will answer you question. https://askubuntu.com/questions/92766/how-to-disable-fancy-visual-effects-in-gnome-shell#348664

Comment: Thanks, I had found that but can't get any of the recommendations to work :(